# VBA read large Linux-formatted text file starting from specific line without reading whole file into memory

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large Linux-formatted (i.e. linefeed character for a new line) text file that is a "status" file for a program as it runs. This file is updated while the program is running. It outputs some useful messages and periodic header information, but also lines of numerical status data separated by spaces. Because it is a piece of commercial software (Abaqus /Explicit), I can't do anything to modify how it writes to this status file.

I wrote a VBA script awhile back that opens the file, reads it in as a whole via "Input$", splits the file into lines via "Split(Data, vbLF)", and parses each line to extract the numerical status data and place it into an Excel spreadsheet for me to view and analyze. The problem is that, as the program continues to run, this file gets larger and larger to the point that reading the whole file into Excel is becoming impractical.

I've been trying to figure out a quick way to read the file starting from the line I left off on, without reading the entire thing to memory. I tried to save EOF() to a "helper" cell on the spreadsheet and use that with "Seek" and "Line Input" to jump right to the spot I left off on, but that won't work because "Line Input" doesn't recognize the linefeed character as a new line, only carriage return or carriage return-linefeed.

I spent some time going through other posts and it seemed like the only other solutions required reading the whole file in. Does anyone have any ideas as to how this could be done WITHOUT reading the whole file in?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Maybe shrinking the file-size (sth. like `log-rotate`) or storing the messages in a database is an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do anything to update the program that generates the status file - it's a piece of commercial software. I'll update the post to mention that.

Comment: Perhaps to use `TextStream` from `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and leverage `SkipLine` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
'perhaps this could be modified for new start
Sub read_bookmark()

  Dim linein, tline, endmark, linevalid, filelen, fread
  Dim chx As Byte
  Dim fpath, mes, a



  On Error GoTo ErrHand



  mes = "Enter path & filename of Bookmark import file."

 'fpath = InputBox(mes, "", "c:\temp\bookmarks_12_8_18.html")
  fpath = "c:\temp\test.txt"

  If Len(fpath) = 0 Or (Len(Dir(fpath)) = 0) Then
    MsgBox ("File not found. Program canceled")
    End
  End If



  tline = ""
  linein = ""
  endmark = False
  linevalid = False


  Open fpath For Binary Access Read As #1

  filelen = LOF(1)    ' Get length of file.

  For fread = 1 To filelen


    Get #1, , chx



    If chx = 13 Or chx = 10 Then
       endmark = True
    ElseIf endmark = True Then      'wait till no more endmarks
        endmark = False
        tline = linein
        linevalid = True
        linein = Chr(chx)           'keep chr after endmarks
    Else
      linein = linein + Chr(chx)
    End If



    If linevalid = True Then

       'proc tline
       tline = ""
       linevalid = False

    End If


  Next
  'proc last linein chrs

  MsgBox ("Processing Complete")

Exit Sub

ErrHand:       ' Error-handling routine.
   Close #1
   MsgBox "Error in HTML read " + Error(Err)
   End

End Sub
```